# Convert given "from date" and "to date" to timestamp in seconds.(android application)

Tags: android, date, timestamp

I am developing an android application to get a reports from server in json format. So that I need to give a request as "from" date and "to" date in timestamp.

for ex: user will select from date and to date from the dropdown list so that I need to convert that and pass the "from date" to "00:00:00" timestamp and "to date" to 23:59:59 timestamp ..

How to do this in android . Please give advice and suggestions.

Regards
Anand

Comment: "I need to convert that and pass the "from date" to "00:00:00" timestamp and "to date" to 23:59:59 timestamp .." could not understand this. You are picking Dates, then how come you are giving Time to your server? Can you give an example?